# Problem with GNU Screen when using Emacs C-x C-s (save-buffer)

Tags: linux, emacs, gnu-screen

When I am using emacs under GNU Screen, if I call C-x C-s screen hangs and does not respond to any keyboard input.

I can't reproduce this, but at least one time per day I have to kill my screen session and restart it.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: *Which* Unix? There are many differences in terminal device handling between Linux, BSD, Solaris, ...

Comment: I am actually using Putty to ssh into a Ubuntu Server LTS instance.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> is the "Pause transmission" (XOFF) [flow control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control) character. Usually it's handled by the tty driver, or in this case Screen. Its opposite is XON, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>.

When you launch Emacs, it normally takes over most of the special characters (not just flow control, but also the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> "Interrupt", for example).

- Use <kbd>C-a</kbd> `:flow off` to disable flow-control for this Screen window.

  Confirm with <kbd>C-a</kbd> `:info` (look for `-flow` in the pop-up).
- If it doesn't help, try `stty -ixon` or `stty stop undef`.

  (You can do it from a separate window using `stty -f /dev/tty1` or `stty </dev/tty1`.)

On my system (Linux), Screen *does* notice when flow control is disabled for the tty. Your OS might have some limitations, though.

Comment: `:flow off` worked. thanks! any way I can make it permanent?

Comment: @simao: See `defflow` in the manual page of `screen`.

Comment: Elaborating on @simao and @grawity's comments - To permanently disable flow-control (I assume this is the desired result for most people), add the line `defflow off` to your `~/.screenrc` file, or create one in your home directory if it does not already exist. This was sufficient to allow my emacs to function properly inside a `screen` window. This approach should be considered before rebinding any keys.

Comment: This resolved the problem for me, but I have yet to learn why "all of a sudden" screen was put into this mode.... perhaps there is some screen key stroke which enables flow control the I inadvertently typed...???

Comment: We're talking about GNU screen and GNU Emacs, and they did not figure out a way to make both work seamlessly ?? ...

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problems with the locked screen and many more when using emacs under screen. For example, C-a in emacs, that brings you to the beginning of the line, gets intercepted by screen and it doesn't work.

SOLUTION:

Create a file .screenrc in you home directory with the following:

```
#Change escape character to C-u 
escape "^uu"                                                                    
#unbind ctrl+s from xoff in order to be able to search in emacs                 
bind s                                                                          
bind ^S                                                                         
#unbind ctrl+x from lockscreen in order to be able to save in emacs             
bind x                                                                          
bind ^X
```

Then each time you open a new screen instead of using C-a you need to use C-u to enter a new screen command. The other two changes take care of a couple more things I needed to change in order to be able to use emacs under screen without problems.

Comment: `C-u` is an important key for emacs. I don't think it is a good idea, but the idea of changing .screenrc is the better alternative.